# Hide/display div with "select option rule" with pure css

Tags: html, css, dropdown, hide, display

there is good trick to hide/display div or another content with checkboxes/radio inputs and pure css like in example bellow.

```
.theTrick {display:none;}
#display_yes:checked ~ .theTrick {display: block;}
```

```
<input type="radio" id="display_yes" name="display" value="somethin">
<label for="display_yes">YES</label>

<input type="radio" id="display_no" name="display" value="somethin">
<label for="display_no">NO</label>

<div class="theTrick">Hello world!</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dz1vLxqu/

Its pretty cool and **without external scripts**. Is there solution for to do this with dropdown list instead of checkboxes?

```
<select>
<option> 
...
```

Comment: Please add an example of what you want to achieve

Comment: Hide/unhide div based on selected option from dropdown list. With input "radio" it is possible with pure css.

Comment: @Ba2sik Yes, and no.. It's answered my question, but i'm not happy with the answer :( 

 
LcSalazar's  comment did that. ---
It's not actually because of the pseudos. The select has the same pseudos. The point is that radio inputs stay at the same node level as the label. That makes it a sibling. The option however is nested to the select so there's no possible selector.

Comment: So it looks like I must deal with javascript. Unhappy.. :(

Comment: There was hope for some magic css selector.. something like 
select#myDropDown>option[value="mySelect"] ~ .theTrick {display: block;} ..


<select id="myDropDown">
<option value="mySelect">Some value</option>
...
...